# Correctly typing a generic function with optional transformation callback in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function in TypeScript that is meant to convert an array of objects into an object, where each key is a field from the objects in the array, and each value is either the original object or the result of applying a callback function to the object. I'm having trouble correctly typing this function. The main issue is with the callback, which is optional and can return a different type than the original object.

```ts
export const arrToObject = <
  T extends Record<string, any>,
  K extends keyof T = any,
  R extends any = T,
>(
  arr: T[],
  key: K,
  cb?: (item: T, index: number) => R,
) => {
  return arr.reduce((acc, item, i) => {
    if (typeof cb === 'function') {
      acc[item[key]] = cb(item, i);
    } else {
      // Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'R'
      acc[item[key]] = item;
    }
    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, R>);
};
```

For example, given an array of objects like `{ id: 1}, { id: 2}, {id: 3}`, and a callback that returns the id of each object, I want the output to be of type `Record<string, number>`, not `Record<string, number | { id: number }>`.

```ts
const nums = [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }, { id: 3 }];
const obj = arrToObject(nums, 'id', (n) => n.id); // Type should be Record<string, number>
```

What is the correct way to type this function to achieve this behavior?

Comment: You should probably use overloads for this instead? https://tsplay.dev/Nr9x0w